# Using MUI DataGrid, tab navigation across cells does not work with `renderCell` When in row edit mode

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

---

When using `renderEditCell` in a column's definition, once the row is in edit mode, I face these two issues:

1. None of the cells gets the focus
2. Using the tab key on that cell has no effect: it should move to the next cell

If I comment out the `renderEditCell` property, the first issue remains (but I think I can live with it), while the second issue is resolved.

My problem is that I need to render a custom component to allow editing long texts.

I've reproduced the issue in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cell-tab-navigation-not-working-x996v7?file=/src/App.tsx).

What I've tried so far in addition to googling (with no results):

- Using the `useGridApiContext` and `apiRef.current.setEditCellValue`.
- Forcing the `tabIndex` prop; only later, I figured I should not touch it because the field is already in a wrapper element with a `tabIndex` anyway.
- Reading the docs too many times. The [Accessibility page](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/accessibility/#keyboard-navigation) does not go in details when it comes to the "edit" mode.

Comment: I am facing the same issue... Once I've migrated to v6, tab indexing in custom cells stopped working...
To be honest, there is more then one issue with the v5->v6 migration that isn't documented properly and is just plainly wrong: setRowMode was replaced with startRowEditMode but migration points to startRowMode (missing "Edit" at the end)...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I have custom renderEditCell components for each column... tabbing doesn't work at all (oddly, it does nothing).  I've tried many things and can't get it going.  I'm using x-data-grid 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9406

The custom edit component must focus the input manually when `hasFocus` is true. This fixes your second issue.

```
const LongTextCellEdit: FC<LongTextCellEditProps> = ({
  params,
  textFieldProps
}) => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
  const { id, value: valueProp, field, error } = params;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(valueProp);
  const reference = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(valueProp);
  }, [valueProp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (params.hasFocus) {
      reference.current!.focus();
    }
  }, [params.hasFocus]);

  const handleValueChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value; // The new value entered by the user
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id,
      field,
      value: newValue,
      debounceMs: 200
    });

    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="column" width="100%" alignSelf="flex-start">
      <TextareaAutosize
        ref={reference}
        minRows={1}
        maxRows={10}
        {...textFieldProps}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
      />
      {!!error && <Alert color="error">{error}</Alert>}
    </Stack>
  );
};
```